# Fix gaps in xyz tile basemap with QGIS

Tags: qgis, tiles, basemap, xyz

I'm making a map and want to use the Stamen terrain background basemap because it looks good. The issue is that there are a number of tiles that appear to be missing at the higher resolution (i.e. when I zoom in a large chunk just doesn't load). I don't mind the lower resolution tiles filling the empty gaps, does anyone know how I could achieve this?

Here are two images, the upper showing slightly more zoomed out while the lower shows zoomed in with the tiles missing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you include details about the URL you use to get these tiles and what your layout properties (page size & export dpi)?

Comment: I have a very hard time avoiding this in any map. But it's very inconsistent. On different days (or minutes) or slightly different zoom levels it can look considerably different.